# First visit of intervals for an irrational rotation

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

I suppose that what I look for is known, but I can't find it.

Let $\left\lbrace I_n=[a_n,b_n)\right\rbrace$ and $\left\lbrace J_n=[b_n,c]\right\rbrace$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) be two countable families of intervals in the unit circle $S^1$. Notice that $I_n$ and $J_n$ are adjacent for every $n$, and that the extremum $c$ is fixed. Assume that the total length of every pair goes to 0, that is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|c-a_n|= 0.$$ Assume also that the length of the "left" interval is a higher order infinitesimal than the length of the "right" one, that is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|b_n-a_n|}{|c-b_n|}= 0.$$

Now let $R:S^1\to S^1$ be an irrational rotation. I say that $x\in S^1$ ultimately first visits $J_n$ if, for every sufficiently large $n$, $$\min\left\lbrace k:R^k(x)\in J_n\right\rbrace<\min\left\lbrace k:R^k(x)\in I_n\right\rbrace.$$
Now my question: is it possible to take the families $\{I_n\}$ and $\{J_n\}$ such that every point in $S^1$ ultimately first visits $J_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. In the following I will use $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$ instead of $[a_n,b_n)$ (this is not a problem, you can just increase $a_n$ a bit so that the statement with $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$ is stronger).

For fixed $n$, we say that $x$ first visits $J_n$ if $\min\left\lbrace k:R^k(x)\in J_n\right\rbrace<\min\left\lbrace k:R^k(x)\in I_n\right\rbrace$. So the set of points that first visit $J_n$ is $A_n:=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\left(R^{-m}J_n\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{m-1}R^{-k}I_n\right)$.

Then the set of points that ultimately first visit $J_n$ is $X:=\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=N}^\infty A_n$. What we want is $X=\mathbb{S}^1$, or equivalently, $\varnothing=\mathbb{S}^1\setminus X=\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty(\mathbb{S}^1\setminus A_n)$. Moreover, $\mathbb{S}^1\setminus A_n$ is the set of points that first visit $I_n$, that is, $B_n:=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\left(R^{-m}I_n\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{m-1}R^{-k}J_n\right)$.

So, we want $\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n=\varnothing$. However, for each $N$, the set $\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n$ is open and dense: it is open because $B_n$ is open for all $n$. To check that it is dense, we will prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $n$ such that $B_n$ is [$\varepsilon$-dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set#Related_notions) in $\mathbb{S}^1$. Indeed, let $z$ be the complex number such that $R(x)=zx$ for all $x$. Now let $k$ be such that $\{z,z^2,\dots,z^{k}\}$ is $\varepsilon$-dense in $\mathbb{S}^1$, and let $n$ be so big that the distance between any two points of $\{z,z^2,\dots,z^{k}\}$ is bigger than $|c-a_n|$. This implies that $R^{-a}I_n$ does not intersect $R^{-b}J_n$ if $a,b<k$ (this is obvious if $a=b$, and if not we use that $d(z^{-a},z^{-b})>|c-a_n|$, so as $I_n$ and $J_n$ are contained in an interval of length $|c-a_n|$, $z^{-a}I_n$ doesn't intersect $z^{-b}J_n$). So $B_n$ contains $\bigcup_{m=1}^k\left(R^{-m}I_n\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{m-1}R^{-k}J_n\right)=\bigcup_{m=1}^kR^{-m}I_n$, which is $\varepsilon$-dense in $\mathbb{S}^1$ as we wanted.

So as $\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n$ is open and dense for all $N$, by Baire's theorem $\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n$ is nonempty.

Comment: Still didn't have time to look closely, but two things: 1. $B_n:=A_n$ must be just $B_n:=$... right? 2. the conclusion is a bit suspicious, as by your reasoning $\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n$ is not only nonempty, but even comeager. That's strange, no?

Comment: You are right about the typo. I guess it's strange? Honestly I didn't think about it that much, since for example meager sets can have full measure

Comment: Yeah but why the set of points that first visit the small one should be topologically larger than the set of those visiting first the large one? Anyway, I'll check it later, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "larger". I haven't even used that the $I_n$ are smaller than the $J_n$ when $n$ goes to infinity, in fact you can change $I_n$ to be the interior of $J_n$ and change $J_n$ be the closure of $I_n$ and the result still holds

Comment: Ok, I finally had the time to properly read your answer. You are right! In my previous comments I confused $S^1\setminus X$ with the set of points that ultimately first visit $I_n$. In conclusion, a comeagre subset of $S^1$ is made of points that infinitely many times visit  $I_n$ first and infinitely many times visit $J_n$ first, and the only really important ingredient is that they are open and nonempty.

Comment: Yes, that is the important ingredient, and also that they are disjoint and $I_n\cup J_n$ is contained in a small interval with length convergent to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ (this is to ensure that $R(J_n)$ does not contain $I_n$ for all $n$, or similar cases)

Comment: I added a bit more detail to make that clear

Comment: I suppose I could be confused, but I don't think you can work with $I_n$ and $J_n$ not disjoint. Clearly then for $a=b$, $R^{-a} I_n$ and $R^{-b}J_n$ are not disjoint, and I think you need them to be for small $a,b$ in your proof.

Comment: In fact I'm pretty sure that under the OP restrictions on length, the set of pts. visiting $J_n$ before $I_n$ ultimately has Lebesgue measure zero (not needing the assumption that $I_n$ and $J_n$ adjacent and disjoint, which is needed for Saul's very clever proof), but I haven't been able to get time to write details.

Comment: I don't understand. By definition, $I_n$ and $J_n$ are disjoint, so $R^{-a}I_n$ and $R^{-a}J_n$ are disjoint. Oh, or maybe you meant if we can extend the problem to $I_n,J_n$ not being disjoint. In that case I would have to think about which conditions you can impose on them, I guess. At first I also tried a measure theoretic argument, but in the end this is what worked

Comment: You said you could even make $J_n$ closure of $I_n$ and I'm saying I don't think you can with your proof, that's all.

Comment: Oh no, I meant making $J_n$ the closure of $I_n$ **and** making $I_n$ the interior of $J_n$. So basically swapping $I_n$ and $J_n$. But yes, that was expressed in a confusing manner

Comment: Got it! I am interested in the non disjoint case because there I think it's purely a measure theoretic argument. Will try to write details.

Comment: @RonniePavlov Btw about the non disjoint case, my argument still works if the interior of $I_n$ is not contained in the closure of $J_n$: you can define $J_n'$ as the closure of $J_n$, $I_n'$ as the interior of $I_n\setminus J_n$, and then apply my argument to $I_n',J_n'$

Comment: "...we use that $d(z^{-a},z^{-b})>\varepsilon$". I don't get this. Looks like, setting $\eta=\min_{a,b<k}{d(z^a,z^b)}$, you just need $|c-a_n|<\eta$, which you assumed. If the intersection is nonempty then there is a point whose $a$- and $b$-images are less than $\eta$ apart, which is a contradiction if $a,b<k$.

Comment: True, I wrote $\varepsilon$ instead of $|c-a_n|$. Now it should work